# limit of composition exponential function

Tags: calculus, limits

Let 
$g$ be the function defined by $g(x)=e^{2x+1}$. Find the following limit

$\lim{x\to 0} \frac{g(g(x))-g(e)}{x}$

Comment: use composition derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{g(g(x))-g(e)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{e^{2e^{2x+1}+1}-e^{2e+1}}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\displaystyle\frac{e[e^{{2e}^{2x+1}}-e^{2e}]}{x}.$

One can see that the value of the top and the bottom evaluated at x=0 is 0. Therefore you can use L'Hospital's Rule:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$

Hopefully you can fill in the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule:

$$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(2x+1)\cdot \frac {d}{dx} (\exp)(2x+1)$$

so

$$g'(x)=2e^{2x+1}.$$